# Trajectory between two stable fixed points and an unstable one

Tags: probability, dynamical-systems, fixed-points

Suppose that I have a one dimensional dynamical system with the following characteristic:

> There are three fixed points, out of which the one of the far "left" and the one on the far "right" are stable, while the one in the "middle" is unstable.

I am asking the following question:

*Suppose that a particle starts near the unstable "middle" fixed point, is it possible to know for every repetition of the experiment where will my particle end-up? Or perhaps is there a method I could approximate the probability of ending-up on the "left" or the "right" stable fixed point?*

I searched a bit around the bibliography and the only thing similar to what I am looking for is *"splitting probabilities"* but that is not helpful in my case.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a thought: When you start in the middle but then the distance from the particle to either of the stable fixed points is the same! but now can we exactly place the particle at the middle? I mean to introduce the error! then one of the distance gets shortest nd the particle will flow in that direction.

Comment: @BAYMAX Thanks for taking the time to respond. It is actually a good thought and in principal that is what it is expected to happen. However, as sometimes the particle is placed a bit to the "left" or a bit to the "right", I would be interested into learning what is the probability of the particle ending up left or right. Imagine that your particle "jumps" from the middle point to the left or to the right with a probability 1/2 (completely random) and then it follows the trajectory towards one of the stable points.

Comment: May be similar logic to the concept if a dipole?  Also worthwile to thik of this as an electrostatic problem where two stable points are say positive charge and the unsfable one a negative charge, then where the particle goes depends on which of the fixed point is more stable than other? U can always code it up

Comment: You can code it up taking your system and randomly taking say 500 initial conditions, and then count number of times you end with  left or right, and u get the probability

Comment: yeap i have done so however I was looking for something more analytical rather than numerical to approach this